# Supporting the deep copy operation on a custom class?

Tags: python, copy

I have a `dict` subclass that adds new methods and features, The main thing that I wanted to support is recursive update which works by updating every nested `dict` one by one unlike the `dict.update` method.

I'm using the `copy.deepcopy` function just like any other object, the problem is that it's not working when I added attribute access to this class:

```
__getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
__setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
__delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

Now I get this error:

```
KeyError: '__deepcopy__'
```

The `copy.deepcopy` function is trying to use a `__deepcopy__` method on this object:

```
copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
```

Why after adding the `__getattr__` this happened ? is there a way to fix it without implementing a `__deepcopy__` method ?

---

I never used the `__deepcopy__` method so I tried adding one, and this is what I have:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    # create a new instance of this object
    new_object = type(self)()

    # iterate over the items of this object and copy each one
    for key, value in self.iteritems():
        new_object[key] = copy.deepcopy(value, memo)

    return new_object
```

Is this the right way to implement `__deepcopy__` ?

Comment: Where's the rest of the class definition? Have you tested the implementation in the second half of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement `__deepcopy__` here.

The problem is that your `__getattr__` always calls `__getitem__`, which will raise a `KeyError` for a nonexistent attribute. But `__getattr__` is expected to raise an `AttributeError` in this case.

The implementation of `getattr` catches the `AttributeError`, but not the `KeyError`, and therefore the exception is unhandled.

You should change `__getattr__` to correctly raise `AttributeError` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to not repeat interjay, who seems to have ninja'd us all, this is a good way to implement what you want relatively safely:

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self

ad = AttributeDict()
ad["a"] = 1
ad.a
#>>> 1

import copy
copy.deepcopy(ad)
#>>> {'a': 1}
```

As classes are just pretty dictionaries, this is actually one of the fastest ways of doing this on CPython. Because it doesn't overload `__getattr__`, this has the standard behaviour you'd expect error-wise.